# R: Regex for extracting mixed fractions

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have one data frame, with one column containing a string of numbers, much like this one

´´´`> df
   id full_quant
54  4  2 14 1/2 
55  4       4 6 
56  4       1/2 
57  4         3 
58  4         1 
59  4      1 1/2`

I want to create a new column $quantity with either a single number, e.g. 1 or 10, or a fraction, or a mixed fraction. Specifically using the first matching pattern of the string - for this reason, I opted for using sub instead of gsub

That's the code I've used

`df$quantity <- sub("(^[1-9]*\\b.[\\d\\\\d]?)", " \\1", df$full_quant)`

But I end up with a duplicate of the first column

```
> df
   id full_quant   quantity
54  4  2 14 1/2   2 14 1/2 
55  4       4 6        4 6 
56  4       1/2        1/2 
57  4         3          3 
58  4         1          1 
59  4      1 1/2      1 1/2
```

What I want to get is this:

`> df
   id full_quant   quantity
54  4  2 14 1/2          2

55  4       4 6          4 
56  4       1/2        1/2 
57  4         3          3 
58  4         1          1 
59  4      1 1/2      1 1/2`

I use RStudio. Would appreciate very much if some could give a hand!!

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. And thanks for putting up such a good first question. It would really help us help you if you put your data , in a dataframe format e.g. df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("a", "b", "c")) obviously with your own data! Thank you.

Comment: Oh, thank you, Peter. I will definetely do it next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below works (but requires `stringr`):

```
df <- data.frame(id = rep(4, 6), 
                 full_quant = c("2 14 1/2", "4 6", "1/2", "3", "1", "1 1/2"))

df$quantity <- stringr::str_extract(df$full_quant, "^([1-9]*(\\s?\\d*\\/\\d)?)")

df

#   id full_quant quantity
# 1  4   2 14 1/2        2
# 2  4        4 6        4
# 3  4        1/2      1/2
# 4  4          3        3
# 5  4          1        1
# 6  4      1 1/2    1 1/2
```

And this is the base R version:

```
df$quantity <- regmatches(df$full_quant, regexpr("^([1-9]*(\\s?\\d*\\/\\d)?)",df$full_quant))
```

or using `sub`:

```
df$quantity <- sub("^([1-9]*(\\s?\\d*\\/\\d)?).*", "\\1", df$full_quant)
```

Comment: It works, thanks Bas!! May I ask though why it isn't possible to do it using sub?

Comment: It can be done with `sub` (see edit). I always find using `sub` for these tasks a bit counter-intuitive, though, so that was why I didn't reach for it immediately. Note that I had to change the regular expression for it to work.

Comment: Why do cou find `sub` counter-intuitive for such tasks? and why does you have to change the regex? I thought that regex was a one-fits-all kinda language . Thank you!

Comment: `sub` is meant to replace (substitute) a string by another. Therefore we need to match the entire string, wrap the part we want to keep in brackets `()`, and replace everything with `\\1`. If we use `string_extract`, the regex only has to match the part we want to keep, rather than the entire string.

Comment: Bas, I tried using this solution for a string with a different format. df <- data.table(string = c("100 g ice", "500 grams orange", "1/2 tablespoon ginger", "1 1/2 beefs") )
 
I thought that this line of regex would be still capable of identifying and extracting the numbers. Both commands  return "1", "", "1/2", "1 1/2". Do you know what's the problem & how we could adapt the code?

Comment: If you replace the [1-9] with [0-9], it should work! The current regex does not allow zeros.

Comment: Yes, it did - thanks, Bas! Another problem was that in some of my rows in my original dt there was a white space to the left, what didn't go with the ^-command.